# Default value of function parameter in Vim script

Tags: vim

How to specify default value (e.g. 0, None) for a parameter in Vim script?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

From the docs, it seems that arguments can't have default values in Vim script. However, you can emulate this by defining a function with variable number of arguments, and using `a:0` to determine the number of extra arguments and `a:1` through `a:n` to access them:

```
function Foo(bar, ...)
  if a:0 > 0
    let xyzzy = a:1
  else
    let xyzzy = 0
  end
endfunction
```

Comment: A short version using the ternary statement: `let l:xyzzy = a:0 > 0 ? a:1 : 0`.

Answer (score 13):

You can use [get](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#get()) to select an argument in the specific position or a default value if it's not present.

```
function! Foo(bar, ...)
    let baz = get(a:, 1, 0)
endfunction
```

Answer (score 10):

Since [Vim 8.1.1310](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/42ae78cfff171fbd7412306083fe200245d7a7a6) Vim also supports real optional function arguments.

However, that means that most vim installation don't support this yet. Neovim has that feature since version 0.7.0.

Example from [`:help optional-function-argument`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#optional-function-argument):

```
  function Something(key, value = 10)
     echo a:key .. ": " .. a:value
  endfunction
  call Something('empty')   "empfty: 10"
  call Something('key', 20) "key: 20"
```